# Aumentar quantidade de linhas retornadas por select group no MySQL

Tags: mysql, banco-de-dados

Tenho uma tabela com 1 milhão de linhas que preciso fazer um relatório que agrupe os nomes repetidos. Estou fazendo assim `SELECT instituicao, count(*) from base_wos GROUP BY instituicao;`.
Contudo sempre o **MySQL** faz apenas o group dos 1000 primeiros registros, não varrendo por completo a tabela.

Comment: Rodando aqui...

Comment: Sim era isso coloca resposta pra eu te pontuar.

Comment: @Igob, você está usando alguma UI? O MySQL não põe limit na query, quem põe sao algumas interfaces de acesso a ele. Isso geralmente pode ser resolvido com confuguração. Seu teste com limit funcionou simplesmente por ter passado por cima do limit original.

Comment: Para deixar claro, Igob: você está usando o MySQL Workbench e, em caso afirmativo, esse problema do limite ocorre apenas no MySQL Workbench? Que outras ferramentas você usou e em quais delas o problema ocorreu?

Comment: Utilizei o MySQL Workbench. Só precisei setar o valor nele mesmo.

Answer (score 13):

MySQL "não" possui nenhuma configuração definida por padrão para limitar as queries SELECT.

Você provavelmente está usando **MySQL Workbench** que automaticamente coloca **LIMIT 0,1000** em todos os seus SELECTs (Configuração padrão).

Para desconsiderar essa configuração basta usar um **[LIMIT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/select.html)** maior que 1000 em sua query assim workbench irá ler a sua query e verá que já tem um limit definido e não irá colocar nenhum LIMIT em sua query.

A outra opção é remover a configuração do Workbench ("SQL queries > Limit rows").

---

O MySQL tem uma configuração chamada **sql_select_limit** usada para limitar o resultado dos SELECTs mesmo sem utilizar LIMIT, o valor padrão dessa configuração é (2^32)–1 ou (2^64)–1, com certeza ninguém vai exibir um relatório com um valor maior que esses. :)

MySQL Workbench não altera essa configuração, o programa literalmente concatena LIMIT 0,1000 nos SELECTs caso o LIMIT não é definido.

Answer (score 4):

O MySQL Workbench possui uma configuração que por padrão vem configurado para retornar o Limit Rows Count = 1000.

Para alteração, já no workbench e no seu servidor, clique em Edit > Preferences > Aba SQL Queries > No fieldset 'Query Results', desmarque a opção 'Limit Rows'.